# SSIS - Save flat file on another server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

is there any way I can save flat file into another server?
SSIS package is doing SQL select from database and saving into file on same server (server A).

At this point everything is working (even when connected with SQL Job agent).
Then I change directory where to save output.csv

Choose other server and new_output.csv (on server B). path looks \\serverb\test\new_output.csv. I change permissions to folder and file so server A can have access.

But when I run SSIS package I get warning: access denied. I dont get why. I added user and computer to permission.

Is there any other way how to make it? I will be really thankfull if anybody can give me any idea

PS: I try file system task..but mostly, there are tutorials to copy file into same server.

Comment: can you post the error please?

Comment: [Flat File Destination [2]] Warning: Zugriff verweigert
[Flat File Destination [2]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "\\tpv2\test\new_output.csv". [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

Comment: how it is structured task and at which point the error occurred?

Comment: Data  flow - inside is source assist. and flat file. source runs sql command, flat file saves. Progress: Prepare for Execute - 100 percent complete [SSIS.Pipeline] Information: Pre-Execute phase is beginning. Progress: Pre-Execute - 0 percent complete [Flat File Destination [2]] Information: The processing of file "\\tpv2\test\new_output.csv" has started.
[Flat File Destination [2]] Warning: Zugriff verweigert ...so it makes querry, but cant access file.

Comment: have you tried to create the file on the server A before and then move it to the server B ?

Comment: I copy folder from server a to server b with file. Not working..But when I add \\serverb\**c$**\test\new_output.csv ..it was working! Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to try is to create the file on the server A before, and then copy it to the server B.